# ¿Cómo importar archivos csv en MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench, importación

Estoy intentando **importar** la base de datos sobre las piezas de *lego* disponible en Kaggle [aquí para descargarla](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/lego-database).

Soy nuevo en **MySQL** y necesito importar esos datos para practicar con ellos. Buscando en la comunidad, he encontrado un problema muy similar: [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429827/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-mysql-workbench)

Entonces, intento reproducir el ejemplo con mi base de datos:

```
CREATE SCHEMA lego_schema;
CREATE TABLE  lego_schema.pieces(
id integer, color_name varchar(30), rgb varchar(10), is_trans varchar(1)
);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Trabajo\CURSO BIG DATA\Módulo II\2.1 Adquisición del Dato y Almacenamiento SQL\Scripts\colors.csv'
INTO TABLE lego_schema.pieces FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Sin embargo, obtengo el siguiente **error**:

> Error Code: 3948. Loading local data is disabled; this must be enablaed on both the client and the server sides

Con respecto al código ¿Voy por buen camino para lograr la importación de datos?

Con respecto al mensaje de error **¿Cómo puedo habilitar la carga local de datos?**

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que estas importando el fichero csv mediante comandos y no con las opciones de Importar del cliente MySQL Workbench, porque se trata de un fichero muy grande que podría hacer que el cliente no terminara la operación y se bloqueara.

El código parece estar correcto, aunque yo quitaría la línea de ENCLOSED BY, ya que en principio no tienes ningún tipo de carácter del estilo "" o '' para encerrar los datos. Por lo cual el comando quedaría:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Trabajo\CURSO BIG DATA\Módulo II\2.1 Adquisición del Dato y Almacenamiento SQL\Scripts\colors.csv' INTO TABLE pieces.dummy FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Por otro lado, no sé si te has situado en la base de datos correcta antes de lanzar este comando, quiero decir, seleccionar primero la base de datos donde se encuentra el esquema 'pieces' y la tabla 'dummy', si no lo has hecho ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
USE <nombre-basededatos>;
```

Si ya lo habías hecho no es necesario repetir la operación.

Con respecto al error, hay que habilitar la carga de ficheros para poder utilizar el comando **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE**, y hay que hacerlo tanto en la configuración del servidor como en la del cliente de mysql.

- En el servidor, tienes que localizar el fichero de configuración de tu mysql, normalmente se llama "my.cnf" y si utilizas Ubuntu o similar suele estar en la ruta "/etc/mysql/". Una vez lo encuentres, hay que editarlo y buscar las cabeceras de sección "[mysqld]" y "[mysql]" y agregar debajo la variable local-infile o local-infile=1, siempre y cuando esta no exista, si existe cambia su valor a 1, quedando así:

  `[mysqld] local-infile[=1]`   `[mysql] local-infile[=1]`

Una vez realizados estos cambios debes de reiniciar el servidor de mysql:

```
     - En Linux: `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` o `service mysql restart`
     - En Windows: Hay que acceder al apartado Servicios del sistema operativo y reiniciarlo
```

- En el cliente, como estás utilizando MySQL Workbench, lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

  SELECT @@local_infile;

Este comando nos permite ver el valor actual de la variable *local_infile* que es la que nos permite importar ficheros con el comando que estamos utilizando, seguramente aparezca con el valor '0', ya que es su valor por defecto, para cambiarlo temporalmente y poder utilizar el comando *LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE* ejecutamos el siguiente comando:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
```

Si volvemos a ejecutar `SELECT @@local_infile`, veremos que su valor es '1' y por lo tanto ya debería dejarnos importar el fichero.

Comment: El motivo por el que intento importar los archivos mediante comandos es porque no he logrado hacerlo tampoco mediante las opciones del cliente.

Comment: Efectivamente no me he situado en la base de datos y, además, mi schema se llama "lego_schema" y mi tabla "pieces", así que debería modificar la segunda línea del código de mi respuesta. Pero ahora, he decidio eliminar la tabla y al intentar crearla me ha surgido otra duda ¿Debo indicar el número de columnas que contendrá el archivo que deseo importar?¿No hay una forma de crear una tabla sin indicar el número de columnas?

Comment: Acabo de modificar el código para que se vea la creación de la base de datos y de la tabla. también he modificado la segunda línea del código, ya que cometí un error al llamar a la tabla ¿Estoy ahora situado en la base de datos?

Comment: Para crear una tabla siempre tienes que indicar al menos una columna, sino te saldrá un error del estilo `Error Code: 1113. A table must have at least 1 column`.

Comment: Para situarte en la base datos debes usar el comando `USE <nombre-basedatos>;`, cuando ejecutes dicho comando estarás situado en dicha base de datos